# turn function into ramda pipe/compose

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I would like to turn this function:

```
const get1 = (v, d) => path(split(/[[\].]/, d), v);
get1("a.d", {a:{d:"f"}})
```

into a pipe or a compose function without the need  of using it like so:

```
get1("a.d")({a:{d:"f"}})
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess I'm curious as to *why* on two questions.  First, is there something wrong with `fn (a) (b)`?  I'm personally finding that I now lean to that first even when I don't have to.  Is is simply personal preference or is there something deeper there?

Second, why do you want to rewrite a perfectly readable function to use `pipe`/`compose`?  I'm one of the founders of Ramda, and I love the library, but I certainly don't see a need to make everything point-free.

As to *how*, Hitmands already gave a reasonable answer, using Ramda's somewhat odd `useWith`.  An alternative is to `pipe`/`compose` and feed the results into `uncurryN`:

```js
const get2 = uncurryN (2, pipe (split (/[[\].]/), path))

console .log (get2 ("a.d", {a: {d: "f"}}))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {uncurryN, pipe, split, path} = R                     </script>
```

But either of these answers seems *less* readable than the original.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```js
const fn = R.useWith(R.path, [R.split('.'), R.identity]);

console.log(
 fn("a.d")({ a: { d: 'f' } }), //curried call
);
console.log(
 fn("a.d", { a: { d: 'f' } }), //call with two arguments
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```